# Android Room Query never return null?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

```
class LottoRepository(private val dao: LottoDao) {

    suspend fun getLotto(gameNum: Int): LiveData<Lotto> {

        if (dao.getLotto(gameNum) != null) { // This line shows me a tooltip that says it's always true

        }

    }
}

@Dao
interface LottoDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM lotto_numbers_table WHERE game_num = :gameNum")
    fun getLotto(gameNum: Int): LiveData<Lotto>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertLottos(vararg lottos: Lotto)
}

@Entity(tableName = "lotto_numbers_table")
data class Lotto (
    @PrimaryKey @Json(name = "drwNo") @ColumnInfo(name = "game_num")
    val gameNum: Int,
    @Json(name = "drwNoDate") val date: String,
    @Json(name = "drwtNo1") val num1: Int,
    @Json(name = "drwtNo2") val num2: Int,
    @Json(name = "drwtNo3") val num3: Int,
    @Json(name = "drwtNo4") val num4: Int,
    @Json(name = "drwtNo5") val num5: Int,
    @Json(name = "drwtNo6") val num6: Int,
    @Json(name = "bnusNo") val bonusNum: Int,
    @Json(name = "totSellamnt") val totalSale: Long,
    @Json(name = "firstWinamnt") val firstWinnerReward: Long,
    @Json(name = "firstPrzwnerCo") val firstWinnerCount: Int,
    @Json(name = "firstAccumamnt") val firstWinnerTotalReward: Long
)
```

Those are my codes and what I wanted to do is checking if the row matched with gameNum exists. But when I check the null value, Android Studio gives me a message that says it's always true. I think it should be null if there isn't the matched row in the database.

The message is "Condition 'dao.getLotto(gameNum) != null' is always 'true'"

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking for a `LiveData<Lotto>` (which would let you `observe` that to receive updates whenever data is available) if you wanted a single callback with the current state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the Livedata  `(dao.getLotto(gameNum).value)` might be null, but the instance of Livedata will not be null. Its something like `List<Lotto>`, there might not be any Lotto instance in the list, but the List instance is not null [considering the list is created]